# Selenium textarea - in Javascript - explanation

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

i have this piece of html, which is under a dropdown, and which appears after selecting somthing in the dropdown element:

```
<div class="mx-0 w-100 row">
    <textarea id="notes" placeholder="Write here..." required="" class="form-control"> </textarea>
</div>
```

I want to use Selenium to click on it, write something and exit from the textarea.
And actually I did it, but results vary depending on which selector I use, and I don't know why:

Here's my code actually working: I use wait for element visible and enabled because the above dropdown, when opened, covers the textarea. If I don't use them it gives a "not interactable" error.

```
const notes = await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.css('textarea')), delay)
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(notes[0]), delay)
await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(notes[0]), delay)
await notes[0].sendKeys('Something to write')
// this TAB is for exiting from textarea, which let a button to appear
await notes[0].sendKeys(Key.TAB)
```

Now, if instead of the first line I use

```
const notes = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('notes')), delay)
```

or

```
const notes = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath('//*[@id="notes"]')), delay)
```

and replacing obviously `notes[0]` with `notes`,it gives me

```
ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
```

The question is: Why does this happens? I do not like so much selecting an array element with numbers, but actually I am forced to and I don't get why the other selectors aren't working.

Comment: in the 2nd and 3rd case are you still waiting for the element to be visible?

Comment: yes, same identical code!

Comment: Try with `const notes = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(By.id('notes')), delay)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code...

```
const notes = await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.css('textarea')), delay)
```

...works as *notes* is a *list* of all the elements identified as `By.css('textarea')` inducing a certain delay for `elementsLocated()` and fortunately the the first matching element i.e. `notes[0]` is your desired element and you are through.

Definitely, the first matched element using either `By.id('notes')`or `By.xpath('//*[@id="notes"]')` isn't your desired element.

---

### Solution

The best solution would be to make the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) more finer as follows:

- *css*:

  ```
  const notes = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("textarea.form-control#notes")), delay)
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  const notes = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='form-control' and @id='notes']")), delay)
  ```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, I am new to selenium (I started a week ago) and I totally didn't figure out this. Still, is not very clear why the first matched element using `By.id('notes')` doesn't return me the correct element, I mean, it's an ID, it should be unique!

Comment: @Diego There are other elements present on top the desired element with `id` attribute as `notes` and is invisible and hence not your desired element.